# WCF The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:30:00

Tags: c#, wcf

this is my config

```
 <bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBindConfig" closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" portSharingEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This issue occurs in production environment，I cannot reproduce this error.
If I set a sleep time such as 40 * 60 * 1000 (40min) in wcf server method.

```
 public List<CompositeType> GetData(List<CompositeType> value)
    {
        
        List<CompositeType> list = new List<CompositeType>();
        try
        {
           
            Thread.Sleep(40 * 60 * 1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return list;
    }
```

then i can get this error:The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:30:00.
they are different.
my error likes a particular call is not finished in a given time interval.
how can i reproduce this error:  The request channel timed out attempting to send after xx:xx:xx
thanks a lot!

Comment: I have answered your question in Q&A, you can go to Q&A to check. Thanks.

Comment: I created a new wcf service. All configs are default. I just only set sleep on the GetData function. Then after the call from client, 1 min later, I can get error "The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00".
My issue's error is "WCF The request channel timed out attempting to send after xx:xx:xx". The difference is "while waiting for a reply" and "send".
I still cannot get error "WCF The request channel timed out attempting to send after xx:xx:xx".
thanks a lot